# Django admin - hide remove link

Tags: django, django-admin

How can I hide remove link in Django admin? I need to hide it in my code, not in permissions (only user with id=1 can see it no matter if any users are superusers)

Answer (score 0):

This is the wrong way to do things so you're going to find that you're working against the grain to accomplish this.  Permissions/Groups are the appropriate way to handle something like this.

However if you insist you're likely going to need to kludge this by overriding the default admin templates.